# How to multiply all values in one column to make one number?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sum

In SQL Server, I am trying to multiply all values of a calculated column in a table in descending date order, to produce one number.

This is so I can calculate a factor that can be applied to a different table / value, i.e. multiplying every value in the "price rate" column to produce a "price factor"

[image]

So far I have been trying to use exp AND log functions with no luck.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You mentioned _So far I have been trying to use exp AND log functions with no luck._, but it'd be much more helpful to actually show these attempts so we can work with your existing code. You can edit your post to include your attempts. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In absence of an aggregate "product" function in SQL, one method uses arithmetic: you can sum the logarithm of each value, then take the the exponential of the result.

```
select exp(sum(ln(price_rate))) as price_factor
from mytable
```

FOr this to work properly, all values of `price_rate` must be greater than `0`.

Answer (score 2):

There’s no PRODUCT() or MULTIPLY() aggregate function in SQL because it’s so likely to overflow.  However, as you were trying to do, this can be done with LOG and EXP,

```
SELECT EXP(SUM(LOG(price_rate))) as price_factor
FROM yourTable
```

Note that using LOG/EXP like this with integer values will not usually produce exact integer results.